# WCF Service endpoint with return type DataSet is returning an empty DataSet when the client needs a response of null, in ASP.net site

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have an existing ASMX service that I'm in the process of converting to a WCF, and I have an endpoint that returns a DataSet. The client connects to the service as if it were an ASMX, which works for most of the cases it needs to. The one failure I'm experiencing is expecting a null response from the call, but when the WCF Service returns null the client application is translating that into an empty DataSet, which isn't being handled correctly in the clientside code.

When the client adds the service as a service reference, instead of a web reference, it works, null comes back just as expected and it's great. The requirements are to keep the service as a Web Reference, though, with the new endpoint.

Here are sample null responses that Soap is giving.

New WCF

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <ActivityId CorrelationId="d50c1406-ca52-4b8a-9588-94b25d1767d4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <HeartbeatResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <HeartbeatResult i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
      </HeartbeatResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Old ASMX

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <HeartbeatResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a way I can make the WCF service mimic the response that the ASMX was giving back in the case of null?

This is only a problem within certain applications. All the other applications I've tested so far have properly seen the response as null. The problem application is an ASP.net site.

An example of one of the requests in the client code

```
        protected void HeartBeat()
    {
        DataSet ds;
        ds = service.Heartbeat();
        if (PopulateGridView(ds)) { }
        else EmptyGridview();
    }
```

and the services Reference.cs it's going through

```
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("AuthHeaderValue")]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/Heartbeat", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Data.DataSet Heartbeat() {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("Heartbeat", new object[0]);
        return ((System.Data.DataSet)(results[0]));
    }
```

Further:

- System.Net.Cookie properly returns null, and if not null the object is passed correctly.
- String works.
- List is converted to bool[] but also works.
- 'Tuple< ?,?>' gets made into a custom object but works.

It seems like DataSet is the only thing that is having this quirk.

Comment: Do you have access to the code on the client side?

Comment: I do have access to the code, but I can't change it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'd need to see the client side code. If the problem doesn't exist everywhere else, the problem must lie in the request on the client side. I'm guessing there may be a fail-safe implemented to protect against null values, but can't be sure.

Comment: I edited the post to include the Heartbeat call. There's nothing fancy going on from that. I should also add that it returns null through the expected response of a string fine, I'm about to experiment with other types.

Comment: System.Net.Cookie properly returns null, and if not null the object is passed correctly.

String works.

List<Boolean> is converted to bool[] but also works.

Tuple<?,?> gets made into a custom object but works.
It seems like DataSet is the only thing that is having this quirk.